# Stranger using my Apple ID for FaceTime/iMessage

Tags: apple-id

My iPad said someone is using my email to FaceTime and iMessage. I have no idea who the person is. How can I block them from using my email?

Comment: It depends if your email is from Apple @me/Mac/iCloud.com or your email is another provider.

Answer (score 2):

If you suspect someone has access to your Apple ID, change the password immediately. If you can no longer access your account, attempt to [reset the password](http://iforgot.apple.com).